# Get street viewport/bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

On my website, I got a Google Maps autocomplete field which let's the user select an location (for example a city or a street).

Once the user has selected an address I automatically set the bounds of the map to the bounds of the location. For example if the location is a large city, the bounds will be zoomed out quite a bit, while they will be zoomed in if the user inputs a small street.

I want the entire location to be covered within the bound - so if it's a long street then the ENTIRE street should be within the map bounds.

Here is the code I use:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var address = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (address && address.geometry && address.geometry.location) {
        centerCoord = address.geometry.location;
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(centerCoord.lat(), centerCoord.lng()));
        if (address.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(address.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            //this happens when inputting a street - no viewport or bounds are returned. How do I get the entire bounds of the street?
        }
    }
});
```

The issue is the fact that the API apparently doesn't return a viewport or bounds when inputting a street. How can I get the bounds in this case?

Setting the zoom level to a static value (eg. 16) doesn't work since the user could type in either a short street or a long street.

As requested, here's a JsFiddle that showcases my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/cy1o228e/5/.

Try entering a local street such as **Rolighedsvej, Frederiksberg, Denmark** and you will see that no bounds nor viewport is being returned.

Comment: For any "streets" that I geocode there is a bounds parameter (but no viewport parameter), does that not work for you? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip
Thanks for your reply. I have added a JsFiddle along with an example address to use.

Comment: Nobody can help me out here?

Comment: Can it be that it is just a bug of the results google returns, as I see in you provided example all streets have now a viewport...